# Usage of aws_elasticache_replication_group resource with aws provider version 2.15

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

our security team has rolled out some policies and when running terraform plan, terraform has observed the drift and is overwritting the policies. so, in order to retain the policies i have included intelligent_tiering in my code, which comes with aws provider version: 1.51.

So, when i include aws provider 2.15 in my code, plan is failing because  prevent_destroy is set to true for aws_elasticache_replication_group. this will destroy our cache, because of which we will lose all our pipeline data. i am on terraform 0.11.13.

How can i handle the below errors. I read in one of the terraform issues that upgrade to terraform 0.12.2 should work. but we are in contain mode. So, an easier workaround would be helpful. thanks in advance.

Adding below introduced the error:

````
    id      = "intu-lifecycle-s3-int-tier"
    enabled = true
   noncurrent_version_transition {
      days          =  0
      storage_class =  "INTELLIGENT_TIERING"
    }
   transition {
      days          = 5
      storage_class = "INTELLIGENT_TIERING"
    }
}```

   Error: Error running plan: 3 error(s) occurred:

    * module.swimlane.module.elastiCache.aws_elasticache_replication_group.spinnaker_cache: 1 error(s) occurred:

    * module.swimlane.module.elastiCache.aws_elasticache_replication_group.spinnaker_cache: aws_elasticache_replication_group.spinnaker_cache: the plan would destroy this resource, but it currently has lifecycle.prevent_destroy set to true. To avoid this error and continue with the plan, either disable lifecycle.prevent_destroy or adjust the scope of the plan using the -target flag.

    * module.swimlane.module.elastiCache.aws_elasticache_replication_group.clouddriver_cache: 1 error(s) occurred:

    * module.swimlane.module.elastiCache.aws_elasticache_replication_group.clouddriver_cache: aws_elasticache_replication_group.clouddriver_cache: the plan would destroy this resource, but it currently has lifecycle.prevent_destroy set to true. To avoid this error and continue with the plan, either disable lifecycle.prevent_destroy or adjust the scope of the plan using the -target flag.

    * module.swimlane.module.igor.aws_elasticache_replication_group.igor_cache: 1 error(s) occurred:

module.swimlane.module.igor.aws_elasticache_replication_group.igor_cache: aws_elasticache_replication_group.igor_cache: the plan would destroy this resource, but it currently has lifecycle.prevent_destroy set to true. To avoid this error and continue with the plan, either disable lifecycle.prevent_destroy or adjust the scope of the plan using the -target flag.
````

Comment: What does the plan show? Also can you include your Terraform code and highlight what you changed to cause this new plan behaviour?

Comment: plan doesn't go through at all. it just fails with the above error. this is the code i am adding.                                                                                              lifecycle_rule {
    id      = "lifecycle-s3-int-tier"
    enabled = true
   noncurrent_version_transition {
      days          =  0
      storage_class =  "INTELLIGENT_TIERING"
    }
   transition {
      days          = 5
      storage_class = "INTELLIGENT_TIERING"
    }
}

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the Terraform code and the changes you've made instead of leaving it unformatted and unreadable in the comments please? Also what does the plan show if you remove the `prevent_destroy` lifecycle config so you can see why the plan wants to destroy it?